# Rename directory after untar tgz file

Tags: bash, shell, gzip, tar

I have bunch *.tgz files and when I untar them some how the directory name is different than the name of the tgz file. Example: I have the ab.tgz file and it get change to something like 2012_test_ab, I have feeling this happens because during compression file must have gotten rename of this compress file was within a parent directory etc.

But what I want to do is rename the directory to original name of the file.

I have following one line script to run on terminal, but how can I rename?

```
for i in *.tgz; do tar xvf $i -C ../stats/; done
```

How can I modify this to rename the directory thats getting unzip.

Example: When I untar `ab.tgz` it gets extracted to directory name is `2013_03_12_18_26_ab` and the files inside that directory but what I want to do is keep the directory name as ab instead of `2013_03_12_18_26_ab`

I want `ab.tgz` to get extract to `../stats/ab`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work.  It's early though, so my syntax could be a bit off.

```
for i in *.tgz
do 
NEWDIR=`tar -tf $i | head -1 | cut -d/ -f2 | cut -d_ -f6` 
mkdir ../stats/$NEWDIR 
tar xvf $i -C ../stats/$NEWDIR/ 
done
```

or

```
for i in *.tgz; do NEWDIR=`tar -tf $i | head -1 | cut -d/ -f2 | cut -d_ -f6`; mkdir ../stats/$NEWDIR; tar xvf $i -C ../stats/$NEWDIR/; done
```

Comment: `for i in *.tgz; do NEWDIR = `tar -tf $i | head -1 | cut -d/ -f1` mkdir $NEWDIR tar xvf $i -C ../stats/$NEWDIR; done` tried it like this get error NEWDIR command not found

Comment: hmm still giving me same error `#for i in *.tgz; do NEWDIR = ``tar -tf $i | head -1 | cut -d/ -f2`` mkdir $NEWDIR tar xvf $i -C ../stats/$NEWDIR; done`

Comment: Error says bash: NEWDIR: command not found. I am bit confuse.

Comment: yes I am using single quote and getting the same error yes I use single back quote the key shares with tilda?

Comment: Oh, I see the issue.  The variable assignment can't have spaces around the =.  It must be VAR=value, not VAR = value.

Comment: so my tgz file name is ab.gz but it get expand to 2013_03_12_18_26_ab how can I just keep ab only as a directory that get expand too

Comment: just updated the question

Comment: I will try that.. yes it will always in that format can I try this on one line..? if not one line should be running as a shell script..?

Comment: strange thing is when I try oneline I get the dir name as I mentioned in the question:
`2013_03_12_18_26_ab  2013_03_12_18_26_ckb  2013_03_12_18_26_hif  2013_03_12_18_26_lmo  2013_03_12_18_26_pap  2013_03_12_18_26_szl
2013_03_12_18_26_ace`

Comment: Since the solution didn't work I am going to manually do rename dir, `mv 2013_03_12_18_26_ace/ ace`

Comment: Yes I did, same issue still there I posted a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15553425/rename-more-than-one-directory-at-once

Comment: It works fine on my end, so maybe I'm just not following what you are asking.  What happens when you run     tar -tf ab.tgz | head -1 | cut -d/ -f2 | cut -d_ -f6

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all you tar archives end with .tgz extension and there could be multiple dots in the original file name, what about:

```
for i in *.tgz; do tname=$(echo $i | sed -e 's/.tgz//') ; tar xvf $i -C ../stats/$tname; done
```