# Rename more than one directory at once

Tags: bash, shell, dir

I have bunch of directories such as

```
2013_03_12_18_26_am
2013_03_12_18_26_cu
2013_03_12_18_26_ig
2013_03_12_18_26_mdf
2013_03_12_18_26_pih
2013_03_12_18_26_tn
2013_03_12_18_26_an
2013_03_12_18_26_cv
2013_03_12_18_26_ik
2013_03_12_18_26_mhr
2013_03_12_18_26_pnb    
2013_03_12_18_26_to
```

What I want to do is rename them to their last two characters, example: 
2013_03_12_18_26_am to am,
I know I can do this one by one `mv 2013_03_12_18_26_am am` but that would take a long time. Can this be accomplis from the shell script?

I want everything after the last "_" to be the name of the new directory.

Comment: Sometimes, there are three characters after the last `_`. Are you sure you want last two characters?

Comment: Sorry i want every thing after the last _

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assume all (and only all) of your folders are in one directory. So be careful...

Original:

```
marks-mac-pro:test mstanislav$ ls
2013_03_12_18_26_am 2013_03_12_18_26_an 2013_03_12_18_26_cu 2013_03_12_18_26_cv     2013_03_12_18_26_ig 2013_03_12_18_26_ik 2013_03_12_18_26_mdf    2013_03_12_18_26_mhr    2013_03_12_18_26_pih    2013_03_12_18_26_pnb    2013_03_12_18_26_tn 2013_03_12_18_26_to
```

Shell Script:

```
marks-mac-pro:test mstanislav$ for i in `ls .`; do NEW=`echo $i | cut -d_ -f6`; mv $i $NEW; done
```

Result:

```
marks-mac-pro:test mstanislav$ ls
am  an  cu  cv  ig  ik  mdf mhr pih pnb tn  to
```

Please test this before doing it on the real data, just to make sure. Again, only do this in a directory with JUST the folders you want to rename, or re-write the first part for the **ls**
to be more specific.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that those dir-names have no spaces, or other special chars. so you could try:

```
ls|xargs -n1 |sed -r 's/(.*_)(.*)/mv & \2/'
```

to print `mv` cmd for you. if you think all commands are correct, then you just pipe it to `|sh`

note, `ls` part you could change to get only those dirs.

Comment: This is my kind of solution. A one-liner that uses all the right unix tools.

Comment: @JonathanCairns personally I feel like xargs and sed if overkill in this case, when there are perfectly good built-ins to do the job, but to each his own.

Comment: @cmh you're right, it's just preference, but I find it a real pain trying to use bash constructs from the command line (trying to get semicolons in the right place, for instance). As long as it gets the job done though...

Comment: @cmh I feel it is not so bad... It is of course possible that save that xargs, and use `ls -l` and longer sed line (or shorter awk line) to print the `mv a b`... take a look those shellscripts in our real life. this is not "overkill", there are so many `grep|awk|sed|awk|cut|sort|awk...`  :)

Comment: @Kent Sure, it's not going to kill any servers. It just seems needless to spawn `n+2` procs when you can achieve this just using builtins.

Answer (score 2):

If all directories following the above form then in bash you can use the following variable subsitituion to extract the characters after the final `_`

```
var=2013_03_12_18_26_am
echo ${var##*_} #am
```

You can then rename all directories in the folder with:

```
for dir in *_*; do #as there may be more than 2 chars after final _
    new_dir=${dir##*_}
    mv $dir $new_dir
done
```

Of course you will want to add checks to make sure you are only moving directories and that you aren't overwriting anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
 for d in *_??
 do
     newd=$(expr $d : '.*_\([a-z][a-z]*\)')
     mv $d $newd
 done
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the rename command for this, which allows perl regexp like so:

```
rename 's/.*([a-z]{2})$/$1/' *
```